# Duplicate Primary key for Custom ID Even with Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I facing duplicate on Primary key when i declare the custom Id . This problem  happen when adding new data.How i want to add the current id with new id
here my code that give error :
Duplicate entry 'CR0000002' for key 'PRIMARY'Duplicate entry 'CR0000002' for key 'PRIMARY'

by the way database cr-num VARCHAR(255),PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL

```
    Dim crnum As String = "CR00001" '// ID loaded from/saved to...
    Dim iTemp As Integer = 0

    iTemp = CInt(crnum.Substring(4, crnum.Length - 4)) '// get only the #'s from String and Convert them to Integer.
    iTemp += 1 '// increase the ID # + 1.
    crnum = crnum.Substring(0, 4) & iTemp.ToString("00000") '// set the ID back with String and #'s formatted to 5 digit #.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code that you can try. You will have to change your logic though, of appending zeros to the new number.

```
var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YourDataSource;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True");
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 pk,SUBSTRING(pk,3,LEN(pk) -1 ) from testprimary order by 1 desc", con);
con.Open();
var crnum = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

var iTemp = 0;

iTemp = Convert.ToInt32((crnum.Substring(4, crnum.Length - 4)));
iTemp += 1;

crnum = crnum.Substring(0, 4) + iTemp.ToString("00000");
```

Comment: sorry asking u again . what should i declare variable var

Comment: i have try it but still it have same error.. any suggestion or way to be done it

Comment: You still getting the same error? I tried this on my local machine and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: yeahh same error. would you share some of your code..and what your state in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Crnum is initialized to CR00001 every time this code is executed. Then it is incremented to CR00002. So every time this section of code is executed, it tries to use CR00002. Try moving the initialization of crnum, or declare the variable Static.

Comment: @xpda.. so your solution is ? i don't understand?? so what i should declare '  Dim crnum As String = ????

Comment: When the dim statement is executed, it initializes crnum to CR00001. Move it somewhere that doesn't get executed every time the the bottom three statements in your code example are. Alternatively, if you declare it static, it will be initialized only once, which is good, if a static variable will work for you.

Comment: i just do your instruction . i state the private crnum As String = "CR00001" . i put the private at outside the insert command but now.. the same error it duplicate

Comment: You need to get the Max `CRNUM` from the database before you increment it. I suggest write a small query which gets the max CRNUM, like `select TOP 1 CAST(SUBSTRing(CRNUM,2) as int), CRNUM FROM YOURTABLE ORDER BY 1 desc`. this will give you the max CRNUM and now you can increment it with your logic.

Comment: @Nilesh i see your solution but can u give more explanation and how i want to applied in my code.. my newbie in this kind MAx. then how i want to declearc max

Comment: I can show you some sample code but I do not have mysql. I will post an answer in a while.

Comment: @Nilesh tq i really appreciate your kindest.. i will try to implement in my code.thanks ;)